# Reset form on Back button

Tags: javascript, forms, reset

Trying to find an elegant solution to reset a webform (or more specifically two `INPUT Type='hidden'` fields) if a user goes BACK after the form is submitted.

I understand that BACK button does not trigger an onload event.

But is there any way of dealing with this?

Comment: You can use cookies with javascript to mark that the user have been on this page before, or whether he have filled the form before

Comment: can you please suggest the code, i'm not really familiar with cookies

Comment: People usually do not want this. It's extremely annoying especially when coming back from an error page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

when the back button is pressed, `onbeforeunload` event is fired so you can try something like

**jQuery:**

```
$('#form_id').submit(function(){
$(window).unload(function () {
$('input[type="hidden"]').val("reset_value"); 
}
});
```

**javascript:**

```
<form onsubmit="call_function();">
```

**in between script tag:**

```
function call_function(){

window.onbeforeunload = function(){
var input_elems = document.getElementByTagName('input');
for(var i=0;i<input_elems.length;i++){
     if(input_elems[i].type === 'hidden'){
         input_elems[i].innerHTML = "reset_value";
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: that's not javascript, is it?

Comment: that is jquery.. a javascript plugin.. anyway i have included javascript code also, please check

Comment: if just using js, think about using jquery, it is way nicer to work with

Comment: the onsubmit triggers the function. onbeforeunload triggers the function, but the function does not do anything. I added an alert inside onbeforeunload function, the alert gets displayed, but the field still contains the old entry if I go back from the results.php

Comment: there was a small mistake, i missed '[i]' in if condition. by the way if it is working that much, i think you should be able to do rest :)

Comment: it was MY mistake. I was trying to change the value of an element that I did not define inside the function. THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU. You saved my day. A BRILLIANT workaround!

Comment: @dku.rajkumar what if the user populates the form (without submitting) and decides to check another page and then goes back ?

Comment: then write the content inside 'call_function()' outside just between script tag, thats all. when back will be pressed even without submitting the form. it will detect.

Comment: `getElementByTagName` should be `getElementsByTagName` (missing an s)

Answer (score 0):

You could prevent the default submit from fireing, ajax-post the form, then unset the unwanted fields and change the location to a new page. Isnt really nice, but should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

For IE 8 or less you can reset the form :
`document.getElementById('formname').reset();`

For IE 9, Firefox, Chrome you can reset just the fields you want by using:
`elementNodeHere.value = elementNodeHere.getAttribute('value');`

Don't bother with jquery,
`.attr('value')` returns the new value not the original

(`getAttribute` in IE 7 returns the new value only and in IE 8 it can return `NULL`)

Comment: Sounds like a bit of a hack using side effects