# How does Rails persist text in input field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a regular text input field, whose value is submitted via AJAX. After I migrate away from this page, and hit `Back` button, I can still see the value of the field there.

My questions are:

1. Does most of modern browsers support this user-entered values?
2. How can I remove the persisted value using Rails?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is remembering the form input values and displaying them when you go back.  This likely doesn't have anything to do with Rails*.

You can't really do anything via Ruby/Rails code to change this behavior, but you can do it with JavaScript.  Here's a random SO question that covers it: [Reset form on Back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518671/reset-form-on-back-button).

I'm not sure if there's a perfect way to handle this in every browser.  Also note that many users would prefer that the browser keep the form values they've entered.

- Note: I only qualify with "likely" because it is possible to write an app that explicitly remembers form values and restores them when the page is visited again, but by default, Rails isn't going to do that.  It'd involve a fair bit of Rails and JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

1. *Does most of modern browsers support this user-entered values?*

   **Yes, I believe they all support it to various degrees**
2. *How can I remove the persisted value using Rails?*

   **This is a client side issue, not a Rails issue. You could use javascript to clear the input fields**

A similar question and answer: [Clear all fields in a form upon going back with browser back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861181/clear-all-fields-in-a-form-upon-going-back-with-browser-back-button)

**BFCache?** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Working_with_BFCache