# Forcing form button reset when browser "Back" button is used

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've searched through dozens of similar questions here and tried implementing solutions offered but nothing is working.

I have a form on a page, and I fixed the problem of impatient people clicking on 'submit' multiple times by adding an onclick event that calls a javascript that changes the text (value) of the submit button to "please wait" and adds a style class so I can change the button from green to red. This onclick event gets fired just before the script that actually submits the form data. Works great.

However, after form submission a fair number of site visitors use the browser's "Back" button to go back a page, change a few answers on the form and resubmit it - which is fine (it's for a quote and they can choose a few different options to get a different quote).

SO I don't really want to reset the form (although that would be an acceptable solution, even if it's not ideal, since they would then have to start over in filling in the form), I just want to reset the button… because my problem now is that when they go back, the button is STILL red and still says "Please Wait".

Ideally I just want to reset the button back to it's original state.  I have tried many different methods suggested (here and in other forums) to force refresh the page, force reset the form, and to just change the input value back to original - nothing works because the problem is with using the Back button on the browser is that the browser just loads up a cached version of the previous page - nothing is really 'triggered' and the page isn't really reloaded (so the window onload/body onload solutions don't work either).

My question is this:  Is there ANY way to actually force the browser to do SOMETHING when you use the back button that I can work from to reset the button or failing that to reset the form?  Some solution that is reasonably cross-browser compliant?

UPDATE:
In response to @jammykam's request to see the code, here is how I'm changing the button now (note that I'm not actually making it disabled/not clickable, I'm only changing the text and color to indicate the visitors should not keep clicking it - disabling the button makes them unable to fix errors and re-click submit)

In my functions.php file I have a snippet to add an onclick event to the form (I use Gravity Forms and got this from their forum):

```
add_filter("gform_submit_button", "add_change_button_text", 10, 2);
function add_change_button_text($button, $form) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($button);
    $input = $dom->getElementsByTagName('input')->item(0);
    if ($input->hasAttribute('onclick')) {
        $input->setAttribute("onclick","changebtn();".$input->getAttribute("onclick"));
    } else {
        $input->setAttribute("onclick","changebtn();");
    }
    return $dom->saveHtml();
}
```

THEN in my header.php file I have this code that changes the button text and adds a class so I can change the button color:

```
function changebtn() {
    var button = $("input[type='submit']");
    if (button.val() == "Free Quote") {
        button.val("Please Wait");
        button.addClass("plswait');
    } else {
        button.val("Free Quote");
    }
}
```

SO as I mentioned, this works great and changes the button, and has prevented the multiple clicks we were previously getting…..I just haven't been able to change it back when someone uses the "Back" button.

Comment: Can't you add an onload event that will set it the way you want it? So every time the page is loaded it sets to green and submit.

Comment: Post the code of how you stop the submit button being clickable

Comment: Can't you just enable/disable the button? The form can probably still be submitted with the enter key in most browsers anyway.

Comment: Did you try solution there :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518671/reset-form-on-back-button?rq=1

Comment: I tried an unload event but it seems the browser is just going back to a cached version, and not actually doing an "onload" so it isn't working.

I updated my original question to add the code.

I tried disabling the button, but it's still disabled then when the "Back" button is used - I can't seem to get it re-enabled.

Comment: @Yoann, I did but not sure I'm implementing it correctly - seems to me it has to go on the 'thanks" page that we send people to after submit, so that's where I put it, but it doesn't fire when the back button is pressed. I tried both the jQUery and javascript examples shown, modifying it to my elements.  Here is how I tried the javascript version:
`window.onbeforeunload = function(){
var input_elems = document.getElementByTagName('input');
for(var i=0;i<input_elems.length;i++){
     if(input_elems[i].type === 'submit'){
         input_elems[i].val = "Free Quote";
     }
   }
}`

Comment: Sorry, in my first sentence of my first reply, my browser auto-corrected "onload" to "unload" - I meant to say "I tried an onload event"…..I had to add onload to my browser dictionary :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try using meta tags.

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Also you can use the header Cache-Control option, sending from your server:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-store
```

Comment: OK I just did a bunch of reading on cache control, and it sounds like it would work to force-refresh the original page being returned to from a "Back" button press.  And that *may* be the solution we'll have to accept if we can't find one that fits our ideal, which is to just reset the form button back to it's original, pre-submit state. Ideally we want to leave the form data there so if someone wants to resubmit and only change a few answers, they don't have to start over and fill in the whole form again.  But thank you for this suggestion, it's been very instructive!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I've had this exact same problem and have a fairly simple solution.

Firstly, I stop multiple submits by using the .data function

```
form.on('submit', function(e){

    var jq_this = $(this);

    if(jq_this.data('submitted') === true)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        jq_this.data('submitted', true);
    }
}
```

If the data 'submitted' is set to true, which happens on the first submit, any further submits are prevented.

To stop the page from keeping 'submitted' set to true when the back button is pressed, I have this code block at the bottom of my javascript file

```
$(window).unload(function()
{        
    form.data('submitted', false);
})
```

The .unload function is called when the user leaves the page.

read more about .unload [at the jQuery site](https://api.jquery.com/unload/)

Answer (score 0):

yes there is a technique called AJAX and History Plugin: more info here http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/ another nice one is here: https://github.com/browserstate/history.js

Comment: Thank you for those links -I"m not an actual coder, I've just learned over the years to to adopt and adapt other people's code, so the documentation on those is a little over my head, but I can see the usefulness so I will start reading the tutorials!